# Использование меток класса в качестве цветовой разметки

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

что-то не выходит у меня нагуглить. Я могу легко реализовать это с помощью  seaborn и hue. Но у меня задание курса использовать только matplotlib.

Данные, знаменитые Ирисы, загрузить можно так:

```
from sklearn import datasets
data = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=False)
X = data.data
y = data.target
names = data.target_names
```

Полный текст задачи:

> Нарисуйте точечную диаграмму (scatter plot) всех четырех признаков.
>   Каждый признак должен быть нарисован на отдельном графике. Используйте
>   для этого subplot формата 2 на 2. Графики должны быть читаемыми, т.е.
>   отрегулируйте размер subplot'ов. Добовьте названия признаков к каждому
>   графику в качестве имени графика. Используйте метки классов (y) в
>   качестве цветовой разметки. Добавьте расшифровку цветов,
>   соответствующих меткам классов, в качестве лейблов.

Мое решение:

```
f,axes = plt.subplots(2,2, sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(20,10))
plt.title('Iris')
axes[0,0].scatter(x=range(0, X.shape[0]) ,y=X[:,0], c=y)
axes[0,0].set_title('sepal length (cm)')
axes[0,1].scatter(x=range(0, X.shape[0]) ,y=X[:,1])
axes[0,1].set_title('sepal width (cm)')
axes[1,0].scatter(x=range(0, X.shape[0]) ,y=X[:,2])
axes[1,0].set_title('petal length (cm)')
axes[1,1].scatter(x=range(0, X.shape[0]) ,y=X[:,3])
axes[1,1].set_title('petal width (cm)')
plt.show()
```

Не могу сообразить как использовать в качестве цветов точек значения массива Y. 
Если использовать просто  y, то получается так:

[image]

То есть он красит не первые 50 точек Х, а первые 50 на числовой прямой. Вот так выглядят данные на самом деле,  много перекрытий:

[image]

Спасибо

Comment: у вас `c=y`, вы уверены, что передаете верный список в качестве цвета?

Comment: " Используйте метки классов (y) в качестве цветовой разметки."

Я понял, что ошибка в моем способе задавать Х. 

Можно сделать вот так:
axes[1, 0].scatter(X[:,0],y, c=y, marker='*', cmap="viridis")
Тогда изображение становится осмысленным. Но судя по всему я не понял задание и отсюда все проблемы.

"Каждый признак должен быть нарисован на отдельном графике." Получатся тогда одномерные графики? Прямые с точками? Ведь каждый отдельный признак (их всего 4, содержит только одну цифру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

colors = list(mcolors.TABLEAU_COLORS.values())

f,axes = plt.subplots(2,2, sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(20,10))
for i,ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    for target in np.unique(data.target):
        mask = (y == target)
        ax.scatter(x=np.arange(len(y[mask])), y=X[mask, i], c=colors[target])
    ax.set_title(data.feature_names[i])
    ax.legend(data.target_names)
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, вы не первый раз мне помогаете)

Comment: @VladimirDoronin, всегда рад помочь)

Answer (score 1):

В общем проблема была не в цветах, а в моем понимании задания:

Если буквально следовать инструкции:

> Каждый признак должен быть нарисован на отдельном графике.

То получаетеся нечто такое:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2, figsize=(15,15), sharex=True, sharey = True)
axes[0,0].scatter(X[:,0],y, c=y, cmap="viridis")
axes[0,0].set_title('sepal length (cm)')
axes[0,1].scatter(X[:,1],y, c=y, cmap="viridis")
axes[0,1].set_title('sepal width (cm)')
axes[1, 0].scatter(X[:,2],y, c=y, cmap="viridis")
axes[1,0].set_title('petal length (cm)')
axes[1,1].scatter(X[:,3],y, c=y, cmap="viridis")
axes[1,1].set_title('petal width (cm)')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут нужно поправить размерность и добавить легенду, с этим полагаю разберусь. Но у меня есть устойчивое ощущение, что я не верно понимаю задачу. Если кто предложит более корректное решение условия, поставлю "Лучший ответ". Спасибо.